# modifying dojo.xhrPost request data fields/object with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, xpages, greasemonkey

There is this one website that I need to query some data from every now and then, but it uses pagination, and getting all the data is a lot of trouble. I want to use **greasemonkey** to modify the post request, but apparently it exceeds my skills. (The website uses Xpages and Ajax requests, and my javascript is poor)

When I use **firebug** I can see in the console that  post request consists data fields such as: `$$viewid, $$xspsubmitid` etc. The page number to be displayed is in the  `$$xspsubmitid` field. I would like to modify the post request in the way that upon submission, several requests are sent to the server with different page numbers.

I tried to define a  `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` function to intercept the request data:

```
var open0 = function (method, url, async, user, password) {
    GM_log(url);
    this.realOpen(method, url, async, user, password);
    GM_log(  document.getElementById('view:_id1:cb_view:inputID'));

}
```

but there is no trace of the fields i need to modify. All I get from there is:

`<input id="view:_id1:cb_view:inputID" class="xspInputFieldEditBox" type="text" style="display:none;" name="view:_id1:cb_view:inputID">`

My question is how can I read and modify the object passed to `dojo.xhrPost` or directly modify the above mentioned fields before they are passed over to server?

Comment: You could ask the developer of the site to create a page for you with all the necessary data :-)

Comment: Haha, right... Any other ideas?

Comment: so, you want to aggregate all the pages together?

Comment: Yes. This way, it would be easy to export the data to excel with one simple copy-paste.